# Can I call gedit (or vi) from php?

Tags: php, linux, gedit

We know that we can call linux commands from php using this

```
 `command`
```

I have tried to do this but it field:

```
`gedit file 2>&1`;
```

the error:

```
(gedit:5217): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

How can I call gedit from php?

for the people who don;t know gedit, from gedit man page:

> gedit is the official text editor of the GNOME desktop environment.
>          While aiming at simplicity and ease of use, gedit is a powerful general
>          purpose text editor.  It can be used to create and edit  all  kinds  of
>          text files.

Comment: Since you're already redirecting stderr, what does the output say? Did you set up X11 environment variables?

Comment: calling a command line text editor from php makes little sense. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dagon, why can't I do this?

Comment: why would you **want** to do this ?

Comment: @Dagon, I want to edit the system files from the webpage, so I want to call `gedit` or something similar to, instead of bring the text to a `textarea` to edit it then update the original file

Comment: thats never ever going to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59537/discussion-between-user78050-and-dagon).